# Loading admob banner ad in custom Dialog on Android is giving a blank view

Tags: android, dialog, admob, banner-ads

I'm trying to load a admob banner ad on a Dialog.

```
  final Dialog dlg = new Dialog(getActivity());
  dlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  dlg.setContentView(R.layout.custom_menu_share);    

  LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)dlg.findViewById(R.id.second_top_layout);
  AdView ad = new AdView(getActivity());
  ad.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
  ad.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.banner_ad_unit_id);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                     .addTestDevice("*************")
                                     .build();

  linear.addView(ad);
  ad.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The ads are not coming up, it just shows a blank area instead of a banner ad.
But if I use the same credentials on a full page Activity, the ad comes up correctly.

What might be the problem ?

Comment: You can't load banner ad on dialog because it must need full width (MATCH_PARENT) space to load its UI.

Comment: any workaround or hack that we can apply ?

Comment: Can you post yout layout resource here ?

Comment: I have to do it in Java code. Its the requirement that I have.

Comment: There is a faily simple workaround. You just make the width and height properties to the "wrap_content" on AdView.